# make: *** No rule to make target `init'. Stop

Tags: substrate

I am a novice and am trying out **'Create Your First Substrate Chain'** tutorial.
After following the **'official installation guide'** up to `rustup default stable`, I revert back to 'Create Your First Substrate Chain' tutorial and get up to trying to run `make init` and get the following error `` make: *** No rule to make target `init'.  Stop. ``

Thinking I need to go back and complete the 'official installation guide', I get up to `rustup install nightly-<yyyy-MM-dd>` but then get the error `` zsh: parse error near `\n' ``

I would be very grateful for some help :)

Answer (score 1):

The `make` file was removed from the latest Substrate Node Template (version 3.0.0 at the time of this post).

If you look at the tutorial, they specifically say to follow the tutorial using `v2.0.1`, which should not have this issue.

> ```
> git clone -b v2.0.1 --depth 1 https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template
> ```

If you are trying to use `v3.0.0` (or any version for that matter), you can trigger the `init` manually with:

```
rustup update nightly
rustup update stable
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch Shawn!